# Github Actions / CI: Workflow is not valid

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this code on my ci.yml file. It worked yesterday but it seems it's not working now. Did Github had any update recently?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`branches` is valid for the `push` and `pull_request` events, but not for `workflow_dispatch`. You can see the valid syntax for `workflow_dispatch` [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputs).

Comment: But it was still working yesterday. I'm more curious if there's an update or what.

Comment: Could the event `workflow_dispatch` been changed from `workflow_run` since yesterday? `workflow_run` allows you to filter on branches. GitHub’s docs are open source so you can track any changes to it, and it looks like the most recent change for `workflow_dispatch` was [two months ago](https://github.com/github/docs/blame/main/content/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions.md#L173).